# repaintしてもpaintComponentが呼ばれない。

Tags: java, swing

```
public class BI2DPv extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    BufferedImage bi;//コレに描画してからg2に転写
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Entered in paintComponent");
        //paintComponent（repaint）はbiをg2に転写するだけ。
        if(bi != null)g2.drawImage(bi, null, this);
    }
    //biは別メソッドで生成してあります。
}
```

`JPanel`を継承したJava2D描画用のクラスを用意しました。メインのクラスの方で`BI2DPv`のインスタンスを生成し、`bi2dpv.repaint();`を実行しても`paintComponent`が実行されません。`bi2dpv.repaint();`が呼ばれていることはログで確認してあります。`repaint`を指示しても`paintComponent`が実行されないのはなぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`BI2DPv#repaint()`がどう呼ばれているのかが分からないので推測ですが、その`JPanel`が`JFrame`、または`JApplet`などのトップレベルコンテナに追加されていないのではないでしょうか。

参考: [Top-Level Containers and Containment Hierarchies (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

例えば、以下のサンプルコードでは、一秒ごとに`bi2dpv.repaint();`を実行していますが、`return bi2dpv;`をコメントアウトして、`return new JPanel();`を実行し、`JFrame`に`bi2dpv`を追加しないようにした場合、`bi2dpv`は非表示なので`bi2dpv#repaint()`メソッドを呼んでも`bi2dpv#paintComponent(...)`メソッドは実行されません。

---

**サンプルコード編集**: `JTabbedPane`に`bi2dpv`を追加するよう変更

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BI2DPv extends JPanel {
  BufferedImage bi;//コレに描画してからg2に転写
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    //logger.log(Level.INFO,"Entered in paintComponent");
    System.out.println("paintComponent");
    //paintComponent（repaint）はbiをg2に転写するだけ。
    if (bi != null) {
      g2.drawImage(bi, null, this);
    }
  }
  //biは別メソッドで生成してあります。

  private static JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel bi2dpv = new BI2DPv();
    new Timer(1000, e -> {
      System.out.println("\nbi2dpv.repaint()");
      System.out.println("isDisplayable? " + bi2dpv.isDisplayable());
      System.out.println("isShowing? " + bi2dpv.isShowing());
      System.out.println("isVisible? " + bi2dpv.isVisible());
      bi2dpv.repaint();
    }).start();

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("aaa", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("bbb", bi2dpv);
    return tabbedPane;
    //return new JPanel();
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: '
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
BI2DPv bi2dpv;
public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();//NetBeansによるUI生成メソッド。jPanel6はここで生成され、登録されています。
        bi2dpv = new BI2DPv();
        jPanel6.add(bi2dpv);
    }
}
'
としてコンテナに追加されているはずなのですが・・・

Comment: その`initComponents()`内で`jPanel6`がどのように追加されているかが、重要だと思います。`CardLayout`や`JTabbedPane`で背面に`bi2dpv`が存在する場合などでも、`paintComponent()`メソッドは実行されません。